# How can I automate the "next episode" button in Netflix (mac)?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, macos, ui-automation, browser-automation

**Here's my goal:**
When my daughter wakes up at 4am I'd like to be able to queue the next 4 episodes of Shaun the Sheep (20 min) so I don't have to wake up every 20 min to start the next show. So really I just need to automate clicking the "next episode" button every 20 min or so (or however long the show is). This is for a MAC computer running Snow Leopard.

My first instinct was to see if I could fire some JavaScript to do that, but then noticed that Netflix uses Silverlight, and it doesn't appear as if the "Next episode" button is accessable via JS.

**Preferred methods:**

1. Chrome extension
2. Mac automation tool / scripts / program
3. Stand-alone Mac program
4. Whatever will work

Any thoughts on how this could be accomplished, and what tools / methods / scripts could accomplish this?

Thank you much.

### **Update: My solution **

I was able to write a sikuli script to accomplish just this. Works like a charm.
**Script on github:**
https://github.com/jamischarles/autoplay_net

**Full blog post with the script**:
http://www.jamischarles.com/blog/automating-netflix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) would be able to click the button.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using Sikuli. I'll post my solution here in a few days.

Comment: I started playing with Sikuli yesterday and I am impressed. By the way, feel free to accept my answer, if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Sure. Yours is the closest one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your daughter watches it on the computer, and the episodes have standard time.
Also if the Next button appears consistently at one spot, you could take a look at autohotkey,
that way, you can automate the clicking, and maybe some other stuff to;
you can get auto hot key here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/
and there is some documentation available here:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm (you need this for your project)

Here is a sample script too that simulates a mouse click at a certain location:

```
 ; Move to specified coordinates then left-click once (based on pixels):
 MouseClick, left, 200, 300
```

also @ lesce, your link doesn't lead to any valid app. (sorry can't comment)

Comment: This needs to work on a mac. Autohotkey is a windows-only utility. Unfortunately, this won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iMacros for Chrome . https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/details

Comment: Good idea, but the plugin doesn't seem to be well supported anymore (that's what the comments in the chrome store imply).

Answer (score 0):

[autoFlix](http://pr.ojectblue.com/autoflix/) does just this, but only on Windows.

I've been working on a Mac version, though.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Until then, I've posted my sikuli script up above.